# Is there a better representation which shows multiple lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plot 100 lines. Each line has color based on score. It is very difficult to see any pattern in the figure because lines overlap.

Is there a better representation which shows lines and scores are linked to one another.

I believe some kind of density plot can show the pattern.

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- rep(seq(0, 3.2, 0.01), times = 100)
score <- rep(1:100, each = 321)
y = runif(1000) * score * 0.01


df <- tibble(x = x, 
             score = score, 
             y = y)


ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = x, 
           y = y, 
           group = score,
           color = score)) + 
  geom_line(size = 0.15) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.5) + 
  # legend.position="none") + 
  scale_color_gradient(low = 'blue',  high = 'yellow')
```

Comment: This is likely to get closed because it's asking for an opinion, but the right display depends a lot on what you want (or you want other people) lean from the visualization.  What features of the data are you trying to highlight with these 100 lines?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I want to show that lines with lower score (in bluish color), tends to have lower y values and therefore lie close to x axis.

Comment: Is the x axis meaningful to your situation? If not, you could plot average y per line vs. score, to show the relationship more clearly and quantifiably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a heat map - which you could make by categorizing both `x` and `y` and then taking the average score in each `x`-`y` combination.

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- rep(seq(0, 3.2, 0.01), times = 100)
score <- rep(1:100, each = 321)
y = runif(32100) * score * 0.01


df <- tibble(x = x, 
             score = score, 
             y = y) %>% 
  mutate(x_cat = cut(x, breaks=11), 
         y_cat = cut(y, breaks=11)) %>% 
  group_by(x_cat, y_cat) %>% 
  summarise(score = mean(score), 
            x = median(range(x)), 
            y=median(range(y)))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'x_cat'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.


ggplot(df, aes(x=x_cat, y=y_cat, fill=score)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'blue',  high = 'yellow') + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels=sprintf("%.2f", sort(unique(df$x)))) + 
  scale_y_discrete(labels=sprintf("%.6f", sort(unique(df$y)))) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) + 
  labs(x="X", y="Y", fill="Average\nScore")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The sample data is simply too messy and complex to show in an unfiltered line plot. One option is to show a summary of each line via `geom_smooth`. Although you lose details in the data, it allows you to convey the message that you want the plot to show.

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- rep(seq(0, 3.2, 0.01), times = 100)
score <- rep(1:100, each = 321)
y = runif(32100) * score * 0.01


df <- tibble(x = x, 
             score = score, 
             y = y)


ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = x, 
           y = y, 
           group = score,
           color = score)) + 
  geom_smooth(linewidth = 0.5, se = FALSE) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.5) + 
  scale_color_gradient(low = 'blue',  high = 'yellow')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the x pattern isn't too important, we could just focus on `score` and the average `y` for each. This shows that relationship more clearly.

```
library(dplyr)
df |>
  group_by(score) |>
  summarize(avg_y = mean(y)) |>
  ggplot(aes(score, avg_y)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Or perhaps there's another salient feature of each `score` line, like "average slope" or "spikiness" or "variability vs. linear regression." You could code that to color in this plot. More ideas for time series features here: https://github.com/tidyverts/feasts